# How can I get HTML Code from an URL using Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

how can I get the source code from an URL on the logs?
This code is returning an error message on the logs instead of the HTML data.

Can you please help me and let me know what can I include/change?

Thank you!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var display: UILabel!

    @IBAction func send(_ sender: Any) {


    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let url = URL (string: "https://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/London/forecasts/latest")!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:url)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask (with:request as URLRequest) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print (error!)
            } else {
                if let unrappedData = data {
                    let dataString = NSString(data: unrappedData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                    print (dataString!)
                }
            }

        }

        task.resume()
    }


}
```

Comment: Hello, please provide more details about the error, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We can get the `html` code from the `URL` like below,

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            // Background Thread
        let myURLString = "https://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/London/forecasts/latest"
        guard let myURL = URL(string: myURLString) else {
            print("Error: \(myURLString) doesn't seem to be a valid URL")
            return
        }

        do {
        let myHTMLString = try String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .ascii)
        print("HTML : \(myHTMLString)")
        } catch let error {
        print("Error: \(error)")
        }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // Run UI Updates or call completion block
            }
        }

    }

}
```